# How to find the commit that closed an issue using the GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api, octokit.net

**Problem**: I'm looking for a way to programmatically obtain the Commit Id (SHA) that closed a GitHub Issue. I need to do this for multiple GitHub repositories that have a lot of closed issues.

**What has been done**: I am trying to implement this with [Octokit.net library](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net), but couldn't find anything that would help me (perhaps I wasn't looking in the right place).
Appreciate if someone can point me to the correct API call/method.

Answer (score 0):

Do check if the method [`Octokit.Tests.Integration/Clients/IssuesClientTests.cs#CanCreateRetrieveAndCloseIssue`](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/73feecefb3fdbc881a27eb5ff7a716b4b15cee55/Octokit.Tests.Integration/Clients/IssuesClientTests.cs#L185-L214) could help you retrieve and close an issue.

The code would be:

```
var retrieved = await _issuesClient.Get(_context.RepositoryOwner, _context.RepositoryName, issue.Number);
Assert.NotNull(retrieved);

var closed = _issuesClient.Update(_context.RepositoryOwner, _context.RepositoryName, issue.Number, new IssueUpdate { State = ItemState.Closed }).Result;
Assert.NotNull(closed);
```